# 3 images with the same logic flow, but only the top 2 work. Where is the flaw in my logic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

Edit: found solution. This works: https://codepen.io/kristianBan/pen/RwNdRMO

There are 3 images. When one is clicked, it needs to gain a red outline and remove any outline from the other two with null. The top 2 images work just fine, but once the 3rd (l_mage_img) gets clicked it stays red no matter what. What am I missing here? As far as I can tell all the values are evaluating as they should so I'm very confused.

```js
function character_selection() {
  var k_c = document.getElementById("knight_img");
  var d_c = document.getElementById("d_mage_img");
  var l_c = document.getElementById("l_mage_img");
  var k_clicked;
  var d_clicked;
  var l_clicked;
  var running = true;

  if (running == true) {
    setInterval(function() {
      if (d_clicked == true || l_clicked == true) { //checks for knight
        k_c.style.border = null;
        d_clicked = false;
        l_clicked = false;

      } else {
        k_c.onclick = function() { //turn red to indicate selection
          k_clicked = true;
          k_c.style.border = "solid #FF0000";

        };

      };

      if (k_clicked == true || l_clicked == true) {
        //checks for d mage
        d_c.style.border = null;
        k_clicked = false;
        l_clicked = false;

      } else {
        d_c.onclick = function() {
          d_clicked = true;
          d_c.style.border = "solid #FF0000";
        };

      };

      if (d_clicked == true || k_clicked == true) { //checks for l mage
        l_c.style.border = null;
        d_clicked = false;
        k_clicked = false;


      } else {
        l_c.onclick = function() {
          l_clicked = true;
          l_c.style.border = "solid #FF0000";
        };

      };

    }, 16);

  };
};
character_selection();
```

```css
#battle_menu {
  background-image: url('obsidian2.jpg');
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  font-size: large;
}

#battle_menu>div {
  padding-top: 1vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 10vw;
  border-radius: 8%;
}

#warrior_name,
#d_mage_name,
#l_mage_name {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.441);
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -1vh;
}

#battle_menu>div>img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 10vw;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="battle_menu">

  <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300/B49CFF-BAB3FF/000000/Knight" id="knight_img"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300/B49CFF-BAB3FF/000000/D" id="d_mage_img"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300/B49CFF-BAB3FF/000000/L" id="l_mage_img"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can also add HTML and make the code executable in your question.

Comment: @Nikhil If the images were stored online, yes...this is just a local project. I tried it in codepen and the JS doesn't do anything to the default image icon.

Comment: @ benthedarklord - I added some placeholder pics and made it executable. Make any changes you see fit. I don't see any red outline though. The interval duration is also very less. If you want 16 seconds, enter 16000 (it should be entered in milliseconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is complex to debug. The third image border stays red because we are not resetting it. I couldn't find where. Let us see if someone can find that.

**Another solution:**

Here is a better way to achieve what you want: Just set the border for the image we click and reset the border for other images.

You don't need to add the same onclick function everytime in `setInterval()`. You also don't need those flag variables.

```js
function character_selection() {
  var k_c = document.getElementById("knight_img");
  var d_c = document.getElementById("d_mage_img");
  var l_c = document.getElementById("l_mage_img");

  k_c.onclick = function() {
    k_c.style.border = "solid #FF0000"; // highlight k
    d_c.style.border = null;
    l_c.style.border = null;
  };

  d_c.onclick = function() {
    k_c.style.border = null;
    d_c.style.border = "solid #FF0000"; // highlight d
    l_c.style.border = null;
  };

  l_c.onclick = function() {
    k_c.style.border = null;
    d_c.style.border = null;
    l_c.style.border = "solid #FF0000"; // highlight l
  };

};
character_selection();
```

```css
#battle_menu {
  background-image: url('obsidian2.jpg');
  max-width: fit-content;
  padding-bottom: 1vh;
  max-height: 90vh;
  border-radius: 2%;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  font-size: large;
}

#battle_menu>div {
  padding-top: 1vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 10vw;
  border-radius: 8%;
}

#warrior_name,
#d_mage_name,
#l_mage_name {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.441);
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -1vh;
}

#battle_menu>div>img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 10vw;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="battle_menu">
  <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300/B49CFF-BAB3FF/000000/Knight" id="knight_img"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300/B49CFF-BAB3FF/000000/D" id="d_mage_img"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placeholder.pics/svg/300x300/B49CFF-BAB3FF/000000/L" id="l_mage_img"></div>
</div>
```